# Flotar el contenido de una columna boostrap

Tags: bootstrap, float

Muy buenas, llevo tiempo enredado con algo y acudo a ustedes a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Tengo una columna de boostrap  y me gustaría poder alinear el contenido de esta hacia un lado o hacia otro, he leido que es con float pero no hay forma. Este es el código.

```
<div class="row  ">
            <div class="col-md-2 row-no-padding "  >
                <h5><span class="modal-title label label-default" id="exampleModalLabel">Proyectos</span></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12  row-no-padding"  >
                <label class="checkbox-inline "><input type="checkbox" id="chkOf" value="">Desactivados</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

En este caso, el contenido que quiero pegar completamente a la derecha es el check desactivados. Me gustaria que se mantuviera pegado a la derecha dando igual la resolución de la pantalla.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes aplicarle un estilo con `float: right` al elemento `label`:

```css
.right-align{
  float: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row  ">
    <div class="col-md-2 row-no-padding "  >
        <h5><span class="modal-title label label-default" id="exampleModalLabel">Proyectos</span></h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10  row-no-padding"  >
        <label class="checkbox-inline right-align"><input type="checkbox" id="chkOf" value="">Desactivados</label>
    </div>
</div>
```